# Reledpar Endnotes Issue

Tags: endnotes, reledmac, eledmac, reledpar

this is my very first question, so be patient... :)

I tried to customize the Endnotes in Reledpar (it sould be the same in [r]eledmac), to get the number of pstart printed after the page and before the lineum. Something went wrong, and the pstart is always 1. In my MWE, for instance, it should be " p.2 - 2.1 πολυστίχοις..."

It looks like the pstart counter doesn't work for the endnotes.

Could someone help me fixing that?

MWE:

```
%%% Test file for Endnotes

\documentclass[10pt, twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine}  
\newfontfamily\greekfont{Linux Libertine}

\usepackage{polyglossia}                        
    \setmainlanguage{italian}
    \setotherlanguage[variant=ancient,numerals=arabic]{greek}           

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% COMANDI RELEDMAC / RELEDPAR %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[noledgroup,                                 % Escludo l'uso di note dentro minipage
            noeledsec,                                  % Non uso comandi di sezionamento tipo chapter, section, etc all'interno del txt critico
            series={A,B}]{reledmac}                     % Restringo le serie di note alle sole che uso
\usepackage[advancedshiftedpstarts, nomaxlines]{reledpar}            % settaggi di sincronia. Con Gramond era advancedshiftedpstarts, nomaxlines
%   \renewcommand{\footfudgefiddle}{64}     % alzare il valore se ci sono problemi di giustificazione delle note (v.p.60 manuale)
    \Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
    \Xarrangement[B]{paragraph}

\usepackage{perpage}                        % Per azzerare il counter delle note con lettera a ogni pagina
\usepackage{alphalph}                       % Per poter andare oltre la "z" nelle note con lettera

\lineation{pstart}                              % Definisce la numerazione delle linee ricominciando ad ogni pstart
\lineationR{pstart}                         % Definisce la numerazione delle linee ricominciando ad ogni pstart a destra

\firstlinenum{0}                                %numera ogni linea
\linenumincrement{5}                        % e poi a multipli di 5
\firstlinenumR{0}                               % se numera a dx a partire dalla linea centomila non numera, ovviamente
\linenumincrementR{5}                           % e poi a multipli di 5
\setRlineflag{}                             % Toglie la R dal numero delle linee della pagina di dx

\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{\alphalph{\value{footnoteB}}}  % Mette note a piè di pagina contrassegnate da lettera (alphalph)
\arrangementX[B]{paragraph}                 % Rif in un paragrafo
\MakePerPage{footnoteB@typeset}             % azzera il contatore delle footnoteB (cioè le rif)

%Parametri Endnotes:
\Xendafterpagenumber[A]{~–~\thepstart\hspace*{-2pt}}    %Nelle EndotesA stampa trattino e numero di pstart al posto di parentesi (default)
\Xendafterpagenumber[B]{~–~\thepstart\hspace*{-2pt}}  %Nelle EndotesA stampa trattino e numero di pstart al posto di parentesi (default)
\Xendlemmaseparator[A]{:}                   % Definisce l'elemento di separazione tra lemma e endnote serie A
\Xendlemmaseparator[B]{:}                   % Definisce l'elemento di separazione tra lemma e endnote serie A



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%COMANDI DI BILIOGRAFIA%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[    style=verbose-trad2,    language=italian, backend=biber]{biblatex} 


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INIZIO DOCUMENTO %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{greek}  


\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\numberpstarttrue
\fontsize{9.2}{8}\selectfont    % Per Garamond questa stringa si può commentare, va a posto da solo

\pstart %1  
Ἐν πολλοῖς μέν εἰσιν οἱ ἔλεγχοι \edtext{πολυστίχοις}{\Aendnote{Endote 1.}} τὸ πέρας. \pend

\pstart %2 
Ἐν πολλοῖς μέν εἰσιν οἱ ἔλεγχοι \edtext{πολυστίχοις}{\Aendnote{Endote 2.}} τὸ πέρας. \pend

\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\selectlanguage{italian}        % ma le Endnotes sono percepite come sempre in greco
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
%\lineation{pstart}         % anche nella pagina di dx lineazione ricomincia ad ogni pstart 
\numberpstarttrue
\fontsize{10.4}{14}\selectfont  % Per Garamond questa stringa si può commentare, va a posto da solo
\normalsize

\pstart %1
Test test and test.\pend

\pstart %2 
Test test and test.\pend\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages              

\doendnotes{A}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE is not really Minimual, as you have many thing in your preamble (`\arrangementX`) does not matter for your problem. Also, if the problem is the same with normal reledmac, you should presente a reledmac only MWE. And all your font settings are not need for this problem. Howver, I will try to answer you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in comment, your MWE is not really minimum.

Anyway, here is an explanation to why you have a problem.

1. First of one, in reledmac/reledpar mode, `\thepstart` become `\thepstartL` and `\thepstartR`. When you call `\thepstart` in leftside, it automatically calls `\thepstartL`, but your endnotes are printed outside of leftside, so `\thepstart` send you the current value of `pstart` and not the value of `pstartL`.
2. But changing in `\Xendafterpagenumber` `\thepstart` to `\thepstartL` won't work, as you will get the value of `pstartL` in the time `\doendnotes{A}` is called, so it will be 2.
3. The solution is to write the current value of the `pstartL` in the endnote files at each pstart, using `\toendnotes`, and especially `\toendnotes*` to get the current value. YOu can call it automatically using `\AtEveryPstartCall` (as your are in parallel typesetting, but `\AtEveryPstart` in normal typesetting)

So your code would be

```
%%% Test file for Endnotes

\documentclass[10pt, twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine}  
\newfontfamily\greekfont{Linux Libertine}

\usepackage{polyglossia}                        
    \setmainlanguage{italian}
    \setotherlanguage[variant=ancient,numerals=arabic]{greek}           

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% COMANDI RELEDMAC / RELEDPAR %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[noledgroup,                                 % Escludo l'uso di note dentro minipage
            noeledsec,                                  % Non uso comandi di sezionamento tipo chapter, section, etc all'interno del txt critico
            series={A,B}]{reledmac}                     % Restringo le serie di note alle sole che uso
\usepackage[advancedshiftedpstarts, nomaxlines]{reledpar}            % settaggi di sincronia. Con Gramond era advancedshiftedpstarts, nomaxlines
%   \renewcommand{\footfudgefiddle}{64}     % alzare il valore se ci sono problemi di giustificazione delle note (v.p.60 manuale)
    \Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
    \Xarrangement[B]{paragraph}

\usepackage{perpage}                        % Per azzerare il counter delle note con lettera a ogni pagina
\usepackage{alphalph}                       % Per poter andare oltre la "z" nelle note con lettera

\lineation{pstart}                              % Definisce la numerazione delle linee ricominciando ad ogni pstart
\lineationR{pstart}                         % Definisce la numerazione delle linee ricominciando ad ogni pstart a destra

\firstlinenum{0}                                %numera ogni linea
\linenumincrement{5}                        % e poi a multipli di 5
\firstlinenumR{0}                               % se numera a dx a partire dalla linea centomila non numera, ovviamente
\linenumincrementR{5}                           % e poi a multipli di 5
\setRlineflag{}                             % Toglie la R dal numero delle linee della pagina di dx

\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{\alphalph{\value{footnoteB}}}  % Mette note a piè di pagina contrassegnate da lettera (alphalph)
\arrangementX[B]{paragraph}                 % Rif in un paragrafo
\MakePerPage{footnoteB@typeset}             % azzera il contatore delle footnoteB (cioè le rif)

%Parametri Endnotes:
\AtEveryPstartCall{
  \ifledRcol
    \toendnotes*{\unexpanded{\def\pstartV}{\the\value{pstartR}}}
  \else
    \toendnotes*{\unexpanded{\def\pstartV}{\the\value{pstartL}}}
  \fi
}
\Xendafterpagenumber[A]{~–~\textbf{\pstartV}}    %Nelle EndotesA stampa trattino e numero di pstart al posto di parentesi (default)
\Xendafterpagenumber[B]{~–~\textbf{\pstartV}}  %Nelle EndotesA stampa trattino e numero di pstart al posto di parentesi (default)
\Xendlemmaseparator[A]{:}                   % Definisce l'elemento di separazione tra lemma e endnote serie A
\Xendlemmaseparator[B]{:}                   % Definisce l'elemento di separazione tra lemma e endnote serie A



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%COMANDI DI BILIOGRAFIA%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[    style=verbose-trad2,    language=italian, backend=biber]{biblatex} 


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INIZIO DOCUMENTO %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{greek}  


\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\numberpstarttrue
\fontsize{9.2}{8}\selectfont    % Per Garamond questa stringa si può commentare, va a posto da solo

\pstart %1  
Ἐν πολλοῖς μέν εἰσιν οἱ ἔλεγχοι \edtext{πολυστίχοις}{\Aendnote{Endote 1.}} τὸ πέρας. \pend

\pstart %2 
Ἐν πολλοῖς μέν εἰσιν οἱ ἔλεγχοι \edtext{πολυστίχοις}{\Aendnote{Endote 2.}} τὸ πέρας. \pend

\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\selectlanguage{italian}        % ma le Endnotes sono percepite come sempre in greco
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
%\lineation{pstart}         % anche nella pagina di dx lineazione ricomincia ad ogni pstart 
\numberpstarttrue
\fontsize{10.4}{14}\selectfont  % Per Garamond questa stringa si può commentare, va a posto da solo
\normalsize

\pstart %1
Test test and test.\pend

\pstart %2 
Test test and test.\pend\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages              
\doendnotes{A}
\end{document}
```

However, as your need could be current, I suggest you to open a github issue, to create  a new hook, as there is still `Xpstart`.

I have deleted your negative hspace.